# ggplot2 with reactive Geom lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I was wondering how to add Geomlines based on the reactive input. For example, if I have a checkboxGroupInput (below) to select insurance types, how can we add lines to the ggplot based on the selected insurance types. I would also like to be able to add multiple lines for comparison based upon the checkboxGroupInput. On the UI side we could have as below:

```
                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "Model",                                                                               
                              label = h4("What kind of insurance do you use"),                                                                       
                              choices = c("Compound" = "Compound", "Simple" = "Simple", 
                              "Private" = "Private", "Complex" = "Complex"),
                              selected = "Private"
                                                        )
```

Then on the Server side

```
Mainplot <- renderPlot({                         
 ggplot(df_norm,aes(x=ages)) +     
 # ADD GEOM_LINE HERE
 )
                        })
```

I tried creating an object based on the input then adding it into the plot, however this creates errors throughout. e.g.,

```
Line <- if ((input$Model == "Private") {"geom_line(aes(y=Private_line), size=0.5) +"} else { "  "})
```

And then in the plot

```
Mainplot <- renderPlot({                         
 ggplot(df_norm,aes(x=ages)) +     
 Line()
 )
                        })
```

However, this produces the error "ggplot does not know how to handle RHS".

Thanks for any help you cab provide,
    Conal

Comment: are you trying to or control/filter which group of data gets plotted?

Comment: You should give more reproducible example or use base data.frames, as `mpg` for instance.

Comment: You need to create a dataframe that is reactive to the user's inputs, and then have ggplot2 refer to that data frame to render a plot. You cannot make functions like `geom_line` a reactive object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select` from `dplyr` to select the columns of your dataframe that shall be displayed, `gather` of `tidyr` package to collect them in a dataframe and separate them by color:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "line",                                                                               
                         label = h4("What would you like to plot?"),                                                                       
                         choices = names(mtcars))

    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({             
    validate(need(!is.null(input$line), 'Please tick a box to show a plot.'))
    # 1. mpg is our fixed x-value
    # 2. select variables of mtcars you need using select()
    # 3. gather all selected variables in two columns: variable/value (but not mpg since that is the x value)
    data <- gather(select(mtcars, "mpg", input$line), variable, value, -mpg)

    # the plot, coloured by variable
    ggplot(data, aes(x=mpg, y = value, colour = variable)) + geom_point()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks @shosaco for creating the minimal reproducible example and everyone for their input.  This could work, I would like to create a model from a formulae, e.g., A + Bx, then plot this. Users can select which data to apply to model to (input options). Would I run selected models over the data they select, then cbind() the models into a data.frame, and run this code over that dataset? Thanks again for the solution, however it seems to be producing this on my end:   ERROR: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  "mpg"
*  input$line

Comment: `packageVersion("dplyr")` is probably outdated, try updating with `install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: Yay, that worked! The code runs in Rstudio! Thank you very much