# How to switch between geom_line and geom_bar visualization in ggplot2 in Shiny - R

Tags: r, shiny

I want the user to choose whether they want to see a `geom_line` or a `geom_bar` on the graph.

What should be the best way to do it, using a `checkboxGroupInput`?

Let's say I have this plot with `geom_line`:

```
ggplot(regiao, aes(x=Ano,fill=Regiao, color=Regiao))+
    geom_line(stat='count')
```

and this one with `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(regiao, aes(x=Ano,fill=Regiao, color=Regiao))+
    geom_bar()+
    stat_count()
```

I'd like to know how to set reactively the arguments for the ggplot.

I've searched everywhere but could only find reactive functions for values, not arguments, like this:
[ggplot2 with reactive Geom lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261084/ggplot2-with-reactive-geom-lines)

I guess it should look like this:

```
ggplot(regiao, aes(x=Ano,fill=Regiao,color=Regiao))+
if (input$checkbox == "bars") {
 + geom_bar()+
stat_count()
}
if (input$checkbox=="lines") {
+geom_line(stat='count')
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `ggplot` objects to a variable and build onto it however you need. Outside of a Shiny context, you could do this by referring to a variable, or encapsulating the task of adding onto a `ggplot` in a function. Inside a Shiny context, you can decide what to add to the object based on a user input.

For example, in a plain R context:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  month = 1:10,
  value = runif(10)
)
```

Create the base `ggplot` object. As an example, I also specified a y scale, because the `ggplot` elements like geoms and scales don't have to be added in any kind of order. You might have some specification like a scale that holds regardless of the geom type.

```r
plot_base <- ggplot(df, aes(x = month, y = value)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Then add a geom based on what type of plot. In a Shiny app, this would instead be `input$plot_type`, and take the value of a pair of radio buttons or some other input. That decision-making would go inside your render function, such as `renderPlot`.

```r
plot_type <- "Line"

if(plot_type == "Line") {
  p <- plot_base +
    geom_line()
} else {
  p <- plot_base +
    geom_col()
}
p
```

[image]

Same logic applies with a bar/column. You just wouldn't have to run through the if/else again—it would rerun reactively when the user changes the input.

```r
plot_type <- "Bar"

if(plot_type == "Line") {
  p <- plot_base +
    geom_line()
} else {
  p <- plot_base +
    geom_col()
}
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Could you make both plots and then use the checkbox as a condition to determine what gets output?

```
output$myPlot <- renderPlot(ifelse(input$checkbox == "bars", myBarPlot, myLinePlot))
```